# Flutter Unsupported operation: add on a composite list layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to get a screen composed by a wrap of FilterChip and a (vertical) ListView. The list of FilterChip has to be make up from an attribute of the objects that I have for the main list on the page (the second widget). Here is my code:

```
     class _ListFilmResultsWidgetState extends State<ListFilmResultsWidget> {
    
      Wrap filters = Wrap(direction: Axis.horizontal);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, projectSnap) {
              switch(projectSnap.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

            case ConnectionState.done:
              if(projectSnap.hasData){
                List<Film>? listFilms = projectSnap.data as List<Film>?;
                return
                  ListView(children: [
                    filters,
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: listFilms!.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        Film item = listFilms[index];
                        addFilters(item.genres);
                       
                        return Card(
                            child: Center(
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text('${item.title} (${item.releaseYear})'),
                                subtitle: Text(item.plot!),
                              ),
                            )
                          );
                      }
                      )
                    ]);
              }

          }
          return Container();
        },
        future: _getFilmsDetails(context)
    );
  }


      void addFilters(List<Genre> genres){
        for(int i=0; i<genres.length; i++){
          setState(() {
            filters.children.add(FilterChip
              (label: Text(genres[i].name),
                key: Key("${genres[i].id}"),
                onSelected: (value) => {},
                selected: true));
          });
        }
    
      }
```

So, as you can see when I get an item ( Film item = listFilms[index]; ) I call the method addFilters to take the list of the genres from it and add her to filters (wrap of FilterChip).
Problem is I get the error "Unsupported operation: add", and I guess that's because the ListView where the wrap and the list are placed into is a stateless widget.
How could I sort this out? Is there any way I can add items to the Wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets in Flutter are immutable, which means you cannot modify a widget's parameter once it's created.

You can create a variable that holds a list of `FilterChip` or other data, and then create the `Wrap` widget in the `build` method.

For example:

```
class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  final labels = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            for (final label in labels)
              FilterChip(
                label: Text(label),
                onSelected: (_) {
                  // Add a new `FilterChip` once clicked
                  setState(() => labels.add('D'));
                },
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer gave me the good lead.